# nodejs: how to communicate between two processes on two servers

Tags: node.js, process, broadcast

i am working on NodeJs, my question is:

process A runs on computer A, and process B runs on computer B, now i want to broadcast a message to both of them, how can i make it?

Answer (score 2):

You should look into a message queue.

[Redis](http://redis.io/) has pub/sub capability and is a common backend component.

You could also consider [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) depending on what your requirements are.

Comment: could you tell me the details?

Comment: @howlake, Details for what?  Your question has no details, so I don't know how Daniel could add more details relevant to you.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode), a good very good system of communication between node.js processes.